# VUE (Cli) and Stripe with Node js

Tags: vue.js, stripe-payments

I have the following problem with Stripe in VUE:

(Stripe was installed via "npm Install Stripe" (stripe-node))

In my component I initialize Stripe with:

```js
import Stripe from 'stripe
```

in methods I have a test function:

```html
<template>
 <v-btn 
      type="submit" 
      class="mt-3 success"
      @click="test"
    >
      Test
  </v-btn>
</template>

<script>
import  { db } from "@/plugins/firebase"
import store from '@/store';
import Stripe from 'stripe'

export default {
name: "MMKonfiguration",

data(){
/* some other vars....*/
}

methods:{
async test(){
        const stripe = new Stripe('SecretStripeKey_here')
        const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
            email: 'customer@example.com'
        });

        console.log(customer.id);
}
}
</script>
```

```js
console.log(stripe)
```

returns me a successful object

However any Stripe functions are not executed (in this case stripe.customers.create) but also e.g. stripe.products.retrieve does not work

Does anyone know any advice? Thanks a lot

Comment: Where are you executing `test()`?

Comment: Hi Phil, the function executes on Button click

Comment: Are there any errors reported in your console? Are you sure that the button click is actually bound to the `test` method? It would help if you were able to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (aka show more code)

Comment: I understand that more code explains more in most cases but in this case it would be rather confusing since the component contains some functions that are not relevant to the error.

Basically the test function is a call inside a Vue method. This is triggered by a button (could also be on create or mounts). 

The function is also executed (see post -> Console.log).

Comment: That's why it says **minimal**. Please read the link

Comment: Yop, thanks Phil - I have edit the Original

Answer (score 1):

The `stripe-node` library is a [server-side](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#stripe-nodejs-library) library, it's not meant to run in client applications like this. If you're including your secret key in a client application, it can be recorded and is no longer safe. You should remove this immediately and [roll your key](https://stripe.com/docs/keys#rolling-keys).

The client-side aspects related to payment details collection should use [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js) instead. You can [use a the `loadStripe` helper](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js#usage) in the `@stripe/stripe-js` package to include Stripe.js in a module-friendly way.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the server side!
I have already tried this with the load stripe, however, this supports only payment relevant functions.
Create or update products, for example, is not supported by this library.
You mean that the stripe-node library e.g. only works in a Firebase Cloud Function ?

Comment: You can use `stripe-node` in any node environment - a firebase cloud function is one valid option among many. You just cannot include your secret key in a client application. Doing so is not secure.

Comment: Sry, Noah - now im confused :)
My Application is a Node Application! And my Problem is not the Key Security - that I'm knowing...

Comment: I'm missing some emphasis: it *can* be run in any Node environment, but you *shouldn't* run this in the client, due to the need to use your secret key. You need to set this up with some API calls to a back end server (or serverless functions etc).